# Access index of current element in range-for loop c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

In a pre-c++20 question [Access index in range-for loop (answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43220064/11998382), it was mentioned that

> 2020 note: It would probably be more wise to use a lambda-based solution instead of macro trickery.

Could someone post the lambda-based solution for c++20? Are there any other solutions new to c++20?

---

Edit: I have a main loop which is polymorphic over the size of a vector. Since I have to read and modify this piece of code frequently, I think I'm justified wanting the nicest solution. What happens if I want to use `views::reverse` sometimes in the main loop and not others? (I don't actually need this, and solved my immediate problem after refactoring, but still I'm using [additional initializations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60209974/11998382) so frequently to access the current element in cold development areas of my code base, it's worth finding a solution)

Comment: Just use a good old non-range-based for loop.

Comment: "_Are there any other solutions new to c++20?_" - Perhaps there is something in `std::ranges`. Otherwise you could create a custom iterator. That's nothing special for C++20 though. I would have used that rather than using macros even in C++11 (and possibly even before that). If you're interested in that, please reformulate the question.

Comment: What about the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60209974/4944425) just above the one you linked (or the [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12397568/4944425) one), isn't it enough?

Comment: @TedLyngmo perhaps you could use ranges::subrange with your custom iterator, then your custom iterator could be used with a range-based for loops which could be considered a new solution for c++20. It would then be compatible with range adaptors which is something I want

Comment: @TomHuntington Then the range-v3:answer that Bob__ linked to should work well for you.

Comment: I think one solution is to define a view interface https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface which I'll try to post an answer for

Comment: Your question appears to be an *XY Problem*. See: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm not asking for help about the problem that gave me the motivation to post. I was just trying to justify why finding a c++20 ranges solution might be worth it, since no one seems to think it's justified

Comment: @TomHuntington I think it's justified to try to find a solution using as much of the standard library as possible. I have _very_ limited knowledge about `std::ranges` (and `ranges-v3`) but I now tried making an enumerator for fun, mimicing how I have understood how views work on a high level. I may have gotten it completely wrong though. :) [My try](https://godbolt.org/z/WrPh97bjG)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'd be happy to accept that as an answer, the subtilties of library writing are beyond the scope of the question I think

Comment: @TomHuntington Thanks - but I'm not sure how to formulate that as an answer to the question "_Could someone post the lambda-based solution for c++20? Are there any other solutions new to c++20?_". I think it'll look odd - especially since my range-like enumerator works pre c++20 too :-) I think your own answer to the question is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking into defining a view interface, I decided to use range-v3.

There are several things missing from std::ranges https://stackoverflow.com/a/68172842/11998382, and until they are added in future standards, it is sensible to use range-v3 rather than repeatedly attempting non-trivial implementations yourself.

[image]