# How to increment the C++list's Iterator inside a for loop to iterate over specific pattern say for example each second element?

Tags: c++, list, for-loop, iterator, increment

Usually in C++ one can iterate over each second element by doing so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 2 ){ 
       //do Somthing 
}
```

and for a C++ list (from library `list`) one can iterate over each element like so:

```
std::list<int> dY = {5,4,5,8,9,7,10,4};
std::list<int>::iterator iterdY;
for (iterdY = dY.begin(); iterdY != dY.end(); iterdY++) {
        // do Something
    }
```

**Now my question is what should I write instead of `iterdY++` to iterate over each second element ??**

Comment: Could you not just use a regular `for` loop, without the iterators? (Defeats the point of the question, but might be helpful)

Comment: @cs1349459 No raw for loops!  https://youtu.be/f_tLQl0wLUM?t=583

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment an iterator by 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057529/how-to-increment-an-iterator-by-2)  Just be careful about containers that have an odd number of elements.  It's up to you to prevent incrementing your iterator past the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::advance(iterdY, 2)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

***But*** you can no longer use the comparison `iterdY != dY.end()` because if the list has an odd number of elements you will skip over the end iterator, and into the territory of *undefined behavior*.

You *must* make sure that the list have an even number of elements first, if using iterators, or use some other way to keep track of the iterator not passing beyond the end.

---

If your compiler supports C++23 you can use [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) and `stride_view` to skip over every second element in the container.

See [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172541/c20-stdranges-range-adapter-to-skip-every-nth-element) (using the earlier Ranges v3 library, which is the base for the C++20 standard library ranges).

Using the original [ranges v3 library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) with earlier C++ standards is possible as well.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way is to introduce a second iteration variable.

```
std::list<int> dY;
int n = 0;
std::list<int>::iterator iterdY = {5,4,5,8,9,7,10,4};
for (iterdY = dY.begin(); iterdY != dY.end(); iterdY++, ++n) {
    if ((n % 2) == 0) {
        // do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have defined `n` as an `unsigned` instead. :)

Answer (score 2):

For starters I think you mean a list in this declaration

```
std::list<int>::iterator iterdY = {5,4,5,8,9,7,10,4};
```

like

```
std::list<int> dY = {5,4,5,8,9,7,10,4};
```

instead of the iterator.

You can do something like the following

```
for ( auto it = dY.begin(); it != dY.end(); ++it == dY.end() ? it : ++it ) {
//...
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() 
{
    std::list<int>dY = {5,4,5,8,9,7,10,4}; 

    for ( auto it = dY.begin(); it != dY.end(); ++it == dY.end() ? it : ++it )
    {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';       
}
```

The program output is

```
5 5 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use two steps and a function:

```
auto iterdY = dY.begin();
while (iterDy != dy.end()) {
    do_something(*iterDy++);
    if (iterDy == dY.end())
        break;
    do_something(*iterDy++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After understanding all of suggested answers I would like to propose this solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::list<int> dY = {5,4,5,8,9,10,11}; 
    std::list<int>::iterator it = dY.begin();
    int step = 3; // Here one can change the step to print each third element
    for (int i = 0 ; i < dY.size() ; i+= step )
    {
        std::cout << *it <<'\n';
        std::advance(it, step);
    } 
    std::cout << '\n';       
}
```

output is:

`5 8 11`